# Django Python - Creating a landing page with a prepopulated form

Tags: python, django, cs50

I'm working on a project for CS50's web course where users can visit a Wikipedia mock up and edit entries.

Right now I'm having a hard time getting my entry's editing page to load properly. Right now I can't seem to get the 'entry' title from the Edit Button on the entry page in order for the page to load with the entry title/content. The current implementation throws me this error

```
"Reverse for 'edit_landing' with arguments '('title',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_landing$']"
```

I've tried swapping out "title" for "entry" and even declaring "entry = entry" OR "entry = title" but nothing seems to work. I'm a little confused as to how Django passing variable in a URL still.

I've tried about 4 or 5 implementations and I'm super lost on how to do it. Right now separating the edit landing and edit functionality seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Here is my code so far:

views.py:

```
   def edit_landing_page(request, entry):
    edit = EditEntryForm({'content':(util.get_entry(entry))})
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        {"edit":edit}
    })

def edit(request, entry):
    if request.method == "POST":
        util.save_entry(entry)
        return redirect('wiki'+entry)
    else:
        content = util.get_entry(entry)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
            "title": entry,
        })
```

urls.py:

```
  urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:entry>", views.entry_page, name="entry"),
    path("edit_landing",views.edit_landing_page, name="edit_landing"),
    path("wiki/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
    path("random", views.random_page, name="random"),
    path("create_landing",views.create_landing_page, name="create_landing"),
    path("create_entry",views.create_entry, name="create_entry")
    ]
```

my entry html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}
{{title}}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
{{ entry|safe }}
<a role-"button" class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit_landing' entry%}" method="POST">Edit</a>
{% endblock %}
```

my edit page html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html"%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags%}
{% block title%} Edit Entry {%endblock%}
{% block body %}
<h1>Edit Entry</h1>
<form action= "{% url 'encyclopedia:edit'%}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
{{ form | crispy | safe }}
</div>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL pattern does not define an argument for edit_landing, like for "edit". Thus the reverse does not work.

Comment: Hmm, I changed it to "    path("wiki/<str:title>/edit_landing",views.edit_landing_page, name="edit_landing")" and that still threw a "edit_landing_page() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'" error. Did I need to change it to something else?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Thanks so much!